# Magento 2 How to get this data for password strenght

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.4

I would like to get these variables, I see in the magento structure that there are these data calls, and I would like to know how to call them from another javascript file

and I don't understand what $elm corresponds to.

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Which JS file do you want to get these variables from? Which case (JS event) do you need to use these variables?

Comment: It solved I don't need it anymore

Answer (score 0):

To check if password is valid in checkout, you can check by error list :

```
$('.amcheckout-form-login').validate().errorList.length > 0
```